The antipodal map is homotopic to the identity map for $S^{n}$ if $n$ is odd.
A number of similar questions have already been asked on this site, but I have a "solution" that seems to extend to the case when $n$ is even. I hope somebody can point out the flaw in my logic.
My solution is as follows. Write $x \in S^{n}$ as
\begin{equation}
x= (\text{cos} \theta_{1}, \text{sin}\theta_{1} \text{cos}\theta_{2}, \dots, \text{sin}\theta_{1}\dots \text{sin}\theta_{n-1} \text{cos}\theta_{n}, \text{sin}\theta_{1}\dots \text{sin}\theta_{n+1})
\end{equation}
Now let $H: S^{n} \times I \rightarrow S^{n}$ be defined by
\begin{equation}
H(x, t) = (\text{cos} ( \theta_{1} + t\pi), \text{sin}(\theta_{1} + t\pi) \text{cos}\theta_{2}, \dots, \text{sin}(\theta_{1} + t\pi)\dots \text{sin}\theta_{n-1} \text{cos}\theta_{n}, \text{sin}(\theta_{1} + t\pi)\dots \text{sin}\theta_{n+1})
\end{equation}
This seems to work for $n$ odd as well as even, so I'm assuming something is wrong. Can somebody please point it out?

Your mistake starts at "Write $x\in S^n$ as ...."

I'm not sure I understand. I've noticed now that I haven't transcribed this properly, but I was writing $x$ in terms of spherical coordinates as in here

Try to do it for the circle ($n=1$): Can you find $\theta$ which depends continuously on $x$?

$H$ will be continuous for $n = 1$, but not for higher $n$, in particular not for $n = 2$.
